# I cant figure out why my prompt is not working. What am i missing?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code I am not sure why my prompt is not working. I have two functions where one calls the other. However my prompt box is not coming up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
**here is the function I want to call using the second function place values.
function square()
{
    cells = new Array([document.getElementById("cell00"),document.getElementById("cell01"),document.getElementById("cell02"),document.getElementById("cell03")],
                            [document.getElementById("cell10"),document.getElementById("cell11"),document.getElementById("cell12"),document.getElementById("cell13")],
                            [document.getElementById("cell20"),document.getElementById("cell21"),document.getElementById("cell22"),document.getElementById("cell23")] );
    placevalues();
}<!--square function end-->

function placevalues()
{
    for (var rows=0;rows<4;rows++)
    {
        for (var cols=0;cols<4;cols++)
        {
            cells[rows][cols].innerHTML = prompt("Enter a number for row "+row+"column "+cols);
        } <!--end of second for loop-->
    }<!--end of for loop-->
}<!--end of placevalues function-->
```

Where the function is called:

```
<h3>
<input type="button" value="Check if its a magic square" onclick="square()"/><br>
</h3>
<!--buttons that will be press to initiate the loops-->
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the developer console?

Comment: yeah I check it with lint and there are no errors.

Comment: But when you actually run the code does your browser's dev console show any errors?

Comment: Please be more precise.
Which content is in which file?
Make your comments legitimate for the file they are in.
Better yet, put your code up in a fiddle at JsFiddle.

Comment: Wait - does your real code have html type comments like `<!--square function end-->` embedded in your JavaScript? Should be `//square function end`...

Comment: yeah I have the first it is the way the instructor wants it

Comment: ok ill try the jsfiddle

Comment: Why are you mixing `Array` constructors and array literals?

Comment: ReferenceError: row is not defined